# Why does my excel upload to database work locally but not on Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, epplus

I've looked through the similar postings here with no luck. My Excel upload works fine locally, but then on Azure it gets a nondescript error ("An error occurred while processing your request.)...Does EPPlus not work on Azure?

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Excel"), fileName);
    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    if (upload.ContentLength > 0)
    {

        upload.SaveAs(path);
    }


    FileInfo excel = new FileInfo(path);
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(excel))
    {
        var workbook = package.Workbook;
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
        objConn.Open();

        int totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
        for (int i=2; i<=totalRows; i++)
        {
            string strSQL = "INSERT INTO Upload (Email, TimeStamp, EmployeeId, Name, Title, Department, Race, Gender, AnnualizedBase, AnnualizedTCC) VALUES (" 
                + " '" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId() + "', "
                + " '" + DateTime.Now + "', "
                + " '" + worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Text.ToString() + "', "
                + " '" + worksheet.Cells[i, 2].Text.ToString() + "', "
                + " '" + worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Text.ToString() + "', "
                + " '" + worksheet.Cells[i, 4].Text.ToString() + "', "
                + " '" + worksheet.Cells[i, 5].Text.ToString() + "', "
                + " '" + worksheet.Cells[i, 6].Text.ToString() + "', "
                + worksheet.Cells[i, 7].Value + ", "
                + worksheet.Cells[i, 8].Value 
                + ")";
            var objCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, objConn);
            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ViewBag.Message = "Dataset Uploaded Successfully!";


        }
        objConn.Close();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I've been using EPPlus Core (an unofficial .Net Core port) in an Azure App Service without any trouble so I think the standard package should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have not more knowledge regarding Azure. I have used AWS hosting. I have faced same issue while uploading Excel.

I installed [AccessDatabaseEngine](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=download%20accessdatabaseengine&rlz=1C1CHZL_enIN780IN780&oq=download%20accessdatabaseengine&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.21638j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to my EC2 instance and it's working fine.

If an error is related to ACCESS, make sure user has rights to read/write files/folders on harddrive.

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

EPPlus works also in Azure context.

As you do not provide exact information on which row gives you an error, I’ll just guess that maybe error is with your database connection? Does your connection string works also in Azure environment?

You can also try to investigate error source by adding some logging.